# How can I get message or feed tagged topics using facebook graph api?

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-workplace

when we try to post some messages/photos on the Facebook group, we are able to tag up to five topics on Facebook.

The same we can able to see on the right pane under the topics section as **"see all topics", "popular topics", "other topics"**

How can I get that information through graph API?

at least for a single post, we need to get the tagged info right?

I am trying for a single post to get the topic tag information. I tried searching for all the developer docs. But I am left helpless

### sample format:

*Message*: **The world is under panic of COVID 19**

*Message topic tag*: **COVID 19, panic, virus**

How can we get those tags using graph API?

### tried the following:

`https://graph.facebook.com/v6.0/{group-id}/feed`
`https://graph.facebook.com/v6.0/{group-id_feed-id}?field = action,messagetag,message,placetag,palce`
`https://graph.facebook.com/v6.0/{photo-id}/tags`
`https://graph.facebook.com/v6.0/{group-id}/sponsor_tags`
`https://graph.facebook.com/v6.0/{group-id_feed-id}/attachments`

Comment: I don’t think that is currently possible. If there was any field or edge for this, then it should be mentioned under https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/post

Comment: Tried to use find this endpoint myself too.
Really a bummer it does not exist in the API yet.